# How to manage having two languages in the app

Tags: javascript, java, ios

I am developing an app for both ios and android. Our app is for selling and buying cars. Car specifications fetch through a 3rd party in English and we try to have the app in both languages (Arabic and English). So, what is the best to offer that? We tried to use google translate but it did not work.

Comment: i18n? it's a config file and in url specify the language or detect the browser language and set it automatically

Comment: to clarify: i18n = internationalization

Comment: Some frameworks offer this built-in like Laravel. I'm sure other do too.

Comment: If you only have English text, then you'd need to translate them somehow and hope the end result makes sense. In a general sense it's not possible, and machine translated text can often be distinguished from professionally translated text.

Comment: You do realize that JavaScript is unrelated to Java, right?

Answer (score 0):

The general practice in this case, is to use internationalization, which means you need to develop your UI using the variables instead of labels. You need to map these variables with the text from your application or third party data which is in English or Arabic.